# get information on usb devices (OSX, C++), IOCreatePlugInInterfaceForService fails

Tags: macos, usb, iokit

I'm trying to iterate through USB devices to find USB Mass Storage and obtain PID and VID. For this, I'm trying to get reference on IOUSBDeviceInterface, but IOCreatePlugInInterfaceForService fails with a strange error code: 0x2C7 - "unsupported function". Could someone please tell, what am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <IOKit/IOkitLib.h>
#include <IOKit/usb/IOUSBLib.h>
#include <IOKit/IOCFPlugIn.h>
#include <IOKit/usb/USBSpec.h>
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
CFMutableDictionaryRef matchingDictionary = NULL;
io_iterator_t foundIterator = 0;
io_service_t usbDevice;
matchingDictionary = IOServiceMatching(kIOUSBDeviceClassName);

IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault, matchingDictionary, &foundIterator);

for(usbDevice = IOIteratorNext(foundIterator); usbDevice; usbDevice = IOIteratorNext(foundIterator))
{
    IOCFPlugInInterface** plugin = NULL;
    SInt32 theScore=0;
    IOReturn err;
    err = IOCreatePlugInInterfaceForService(usbDevice, kIOUSBInterfaceUserClientTypeID, kIOCFPlugInInterfaceID, &plugin, &theScore);
    if (err!= 0){
        //for all the devices (including Mass Storage), I get the same 
        //error: system 0x38 (IOKit), code: 0x2C7 (unsupported function) 
        std::cout<<"error, error code: "<<err_get_code(err) <<std::endl;
    }
    else if (plugin && *plugin)
    {
        //never happens
        IOUSBDeviceInterface** usbInterface = NULL;
        (*plugin)->QueryInterface(plugin, CFUUIDGetUUIDBytes(kIOUSBDeviceInterfaceID),(LPVOID*)&usbInterface);
        (*plugin)->Release(plugin);
        if (usbInterface && *usbInterface)
        {
             //other actions with usbInterface
        }       

    }

}
IOObjectRelease(foundIterator);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're matching `IOUSBDevice` services, but attempting to connect with an `IOUSBInterfaceUserClient`. If you want to connect to an `IOUSBDevice` service, the user client type must be `kIOUSBDeviceUserClientTypeID`. If you want an `IOUSBInterfaceUserClient`, you need to match `IOUSBInterface` services.

Comment: Yes, indeed! A stupid mistake of mine, thank you a lot!